# Check if a directory exists with LotusScript

Tags: file-io, lotusscript

This seems like the most basic of things.  There are lots of examples on google, all of which I have put into my code and have gotten the same result.

I beleive I am missing something specific to the language, and it's really getting irritating.

Given

```
pathName$ = "..\..\images\" + artID + "\" + artNum + "\"
    dirTest$ = "..\..\images\" + artID + "\"
    If Dir$(pathName$ , ATTR_DIRECTORY) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Dir"
    Else
        MsgBox "Dir Found!"
    End If
```

(everthing is dimmed correctly)

I have put msgbox's before pathName$ and right before the DIR call, but it fails when it gets to the test.  I know for a fact that the dir doesn't exist in certain scenarios, but I would like to trap the error, not have the script crash on failing to find the dir.

I have tried `DIR (path,16) DIR$(path,16) DIR (path$,16) DIR$(path$,16)` as well as the ATTR_DIRECTORY key word.

How can I gracefully check the existence of a directory in Lotusscript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dir$ command will generate the run-time error code 76 if the directory does not exist. So you can trap the run-time error by adding `On Error 76 Resume Next` to your code:

```
pathName$ = "..\..\images\" + artID + "\" + artNum + "\"
dirTest$ = "..\..\images\" + artID + "\"
On Error 76 Resume Next
If Dir$(pathName$ , ATTR_DIRECTORY) = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Dir"
Else
    MsgBox "Dir Found!"
End If
```

Inspiration: http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Finding-files-and-directories-with-LotusScript

Comment: That website is great for some info, but the inability to quickly login and see the article stops me every time.  I will try the code and post back

Comment: You don't need to login, actually. Just page down and you will see the content.

Comment: ATTR_DIRECTORY=16

Comment: Nowadays, to get around the blockage, i use the wayback machine to find technotes 
on sites like the searchdomino.techtarget.com etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is to test a variant with the Dir$ function result. That's because if the dir path is completely wrong the error 76 gives back a variant containing the error. So it should be managed, like this:

```
`
On Error 76 GoTo PathNotValid
result = Dir$(dirPath$,16)
If result <>"" then
    MessageBox dirPath$ + " found :) "
Else
    MessageBox dirPath$ + " NOT found :( "
End if 

End:
   Exit Sub 
PathNotValid:
   MessageBox dirPath$ + " IS NOT VALID !!!"
   result = ""
   Resume Next
```

`